# Breeze and data type when using a .select

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm curious if anyone has any insight into why adding a .Select to a breeze query and only returning a single column would cause my date field to get parsed differently ?  My thought is both queries should return the same data / use the same meta data for my date fields.

For example

```
Retrieving the entity that includes the date:
    function getACase()
    {
        var returnPromise = Q.defer();
       var caseQuery = breeze.EntityQuery
           .from("case")
           .where("pkCaseID", "eq", 1013)
        return Q.delay(0)
            .then(function()
            {
                return manager.executeQuery(caseQuery)
                    .then (function(data)
                    {
                    returnPromise.resolve();
                    return data.results;
                    })
                    .fail(function(){$log.error("CaseData Query Failed")});
            }) ;
        return returnPromise.promise();
    }
```

CourtDate columns gets converted to a date :  (actual date from database is 1/1/1950)

[image]

```
Retrieving just the date column from the database:
   function retrieveCourtDate ()
    {
        var returnPromise = Q.defer();
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("case")
            .where ("pkCaseID", "eq", 1013)
            .select("CourtDate");
        return Q.delay(0)
            .then(function()
            {
                return manager.executeQuery(query)
                    .then (function(data)
                {
                     returnPromise.resolve();
                    return data.results;
                })
                    .fail(function(){$log.error("Date Query Failed")});
            });
        return returnPromise.promise();
    }
```

CourtDate is not converted:

[image]

Displayed on the screen as:[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay ! We are trying to get our dates down and figure out the best way to handle them.  We are trying to always store exactly what the user input and then display the same date to other users regardless of the timezone they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is **not** a bug *but it is a pain*.  Basically when Breeze executes a query that returns  any known *entityType*, we have metadata that determines what the *dataType* is for every property in the json returned from the server.  This is what allows us to take a json ISO8601 serialized date string like this "1996-07-13T00:00:00.000Z" and convert it to a javascript date object: **Fri Jul 12 17:00:00 PDT 1996**.

The problem is that when you use the Breeze "select" statement the result returned from the server is an anonymous object, and Breeze doesn't know the datatype of any of the properties on this object.  Breeze *does* iterate over all of the properties of the returned object to determine if there are any embedded entities, but it can't determine that a property called "CourtDate" is in fact a date datatype ( we could guess, but there are other issues with that).

*There is a workaround*, for your anonymous objects that contain dates, since you know the properties that are Dates, you can call Breeze's *DataType.parseDateFromServer* method

```
  data.results.forEach(function(anon) {
      anon.CourtDate = breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer(anon.CourtDate);
  }
```

Comment: On related note why does breeze assume we want it converted to the client timezone?  We really want to save and display a specific moment in time and not take into account what timezone the users browser is in.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Breeze does not convert to the current timezone, your browser is doing this by taking a UTC datetime and converting to a localalized date for display purposes only.  Under the covers a javascript date is always a UTC date.